# Gladman's file encryption library = AES in counter mode with HMAC-SHA1 authentication?

Tags: cryptography, aes, hmac, zip

I would like to use Gladman's algorithm to create AES encrypted data in JavaScript. I use the [Crypto-JS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js) library, but its performance is horrible. PBKDF2 is terribly slow, so I switched to another library ([SJCL](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl)) which seems to be over a lot faster.

Crypto-JS has a special *Gladman* mode to give the same result as Gladman's file encryption library (C code). The SJCL doesn't have it, but is constructed pretty modular. It includes PBKDF2, a low-level AES encrypt method, CTR mode, HMAC and SHA1. Seems like all ingredients are there.

I also have the source-code of CTR-Gladman from Crypto-JS. It seems like Gladman uses AES in CTR mode with HMAC-SHA1 used for authentication. It seems that the counting function just results in a 32-bit block that represents the blocknumber. Can anyone confirm if this is correct?